# jenkins permission denied while running cd command

Tags: macos, shell, maven, jenkins

I am fairly new to macOS and I am trying to run a shell script through Jenkins for a maven project.

I just don't know how to give/change permission so that Jenkins can even change a directory.

Command I am trying to run:

```
   #!/bin/bash
   export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
   export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.5.3
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.5.3/bin
   cd /Users/User1/Documents/QA_Automation/Selenium/workspace/TestProject
   mvn clean install  -Dtest=IOSTDMobileTest -Dwebtest.browser=Chrome
```

Output I am getting:

```
  Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Test job 2
 [Test job 2] $ /bin/bash 
 /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins1874710180338230332.sh
 /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins1874710180338230332.sh: line 7: cd: 
/Users/User1/Documents/QA_Automation/Selenium/workspace/TestProject:Permission denied
```

Comment: Does that directory exist?

Comment: Yes the directory exists. When I run the command from the terminal it works and mvn command is able to execute as that directory contains the required pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the next task:

```
cd /home/allex/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorld/
pwd
javac HelloWorld.java
java HelloWorld
```

When I executed it I got the "Permission errors like you" but in my interactive CLI I didn't have problem to access to the directory. Then I realized that the user who execute the command in Jenkins is "jenkins" who didn't have rights access to that directory by executing this command:

```
ls -ld /home/allex/
drwxr-x---. 87 allex allex 4096 Nov 19 08:57 /home/allex/
```

As you can see the user jenkins has no permissions over that directory. Then what I did was add the user jenkins to the group allex with the next command:

```
usermod -a -G allex jenkins
```

And that was all. It's working.